# *ngIf on tr not updated

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, angular-ng-if

I have a tr with an ngIf statement which depends on a function result - the function is executed by click event (toggle(data.code)). 
See my code:
*TableData is a collection of records

```
<tbody *ngFor="let data of TableData" (click)="toggle(data.code)">
   <tr *ngIf="isExpanded(data.code)">
     <td *ngfor="let column of columns">{{column.name}}</td>
   </tr>
```

This is the functions in the component:

```
codesArray: number[] = [];

isExpanded(code)
{
 return (code%10 == 0) || this.codesArray.includes(code); // The second part of the condition changes and should effect the tr
}


toggle(code)
{
    if (this.codesArray.includes(code))
    {
       this.codesArray.splice(this.codesArray.indexOf(code), 1);
    }
    else //This part should happen first and change the tr state 
    {
       this.codesArray.push(code); //This actually happens but the tr not appear  
    }
}
```

Is there a need of a some kind of a change detection ?

Comment: MY MISTAKE - the values which were inserted into the codesArray were not the ones I wanted to display - the code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the ngFor on the body. You will get multiiple table bodies. Try using ng-content.

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of TableData">
   <tr (click)="toggle(data.code)">
      <ng-container *ngIf="isExpanded(data.code)">
        <td *ngfor="let column of columns">{{column.name}}</td>
     </ng-container>
   </tr>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: `ng-container` instead of `ng-content` but otherwise yes don't duplicate the table body.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger change detection using the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) Feature, `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`